# Update en PHP no actualiza tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estimados tengo el siguiente codigo PHP

```
<?php
    $percepcion_cliente = $_POST['percepcion_cliente'];
    $observacion= $_POST['observacion'];

    $id= $_POST['id']; 



    //Conexión a la BD
    $servidor = "168.232.167.46";
    $nombreusuario = "ccwom_vero";
    $password = "Hol@pato";
    $db = "ccwom_callcenter";
    $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $nombreusuario, $password, $db);
    if($conexion->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }else{          

        $sql = "UPDATE feedback_nps SET percepcion_cliente='$percepcion_cliente',observacion='$observacion',retroalimentado='Si' where id= '$id'";
        if($conexion->query($sql) === true){        
        //se guardo correctamente           ?>
                <script languaje="javascript">
                    alert("Registro ingresado con Exito!!!");
                    location.href = "feed_nps_list.php"; 
                </script>
            <?php
        }else{
            die("Error al actualizar datos: " . $conexion->error);
            ?>
                <script languaje="javascript">
                    alert("Registro No Fue ingreado!!!");
                    location.href = "feed_nps_list.php"; 
                </script>
            <?php
        } 
    }     
?>
```

y tengo la siguiente tabla en la base de datos llamada feedback_nps

```
id varchar(11) PK 
cod_gestor varchar(45) 
supervisor varchar(255) 
site varchar(45) 
numero_telefono varchar(45) 
NRO_SS varchar(255) 
tipo varchar(255) 
nombre_cliente varchar(255) 
nota varchar(45) 
fecha_respuesta datetime 
retroalimentado varchar(45) 
recibe_gestor varchar(45) 
nombre_gestor varchar(255) 
observacion varchar(255) 
percepcion_cliente varchar(100)
```

El problema que tengo es que en el código PHP me indica que efectuó la actualización de los datos, pero al revisar el registro en la tabla no se modificaron los campos que estoy cambiando, me podrían ayudar con esta situacion bastante extraña, hice pruebas cambiando el campo ID de INT a VARCHAR, de hecho estaba en INT y aun así no logre que efectuara el cambio en la tabla

Comment: Naturalmente que la consulta realizada sea "true" significa que no hubo problema al ejecutarse , o sea que si encontro la tabla y si encontro los atributos, no siempre es para garantizar que los daos fueron actualizados, posiblemente la variable $percepción_cliente  sobrepase los 100 caracteres definidos en la tabla o los datos recibidos no son los correctos por ejemplo lo que recibes en "$id" por tanto la consulta funciona pero no actualiza porque no encuentra los datos correctos o el, seria bueno que revisaras lo que te  llega en los $_POST[]  con un echo antes de insertarlos en la consulta.

Comment: gracias haré las pruebas y veré que valores tengo en las variables, y lo que esta en $percepcion_cliente es una etiqueta <select> de html y no excede el valor porque yo entrego los valores y en las pruebas coloco un valor pequeño en la observación, pero muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

ya encontré el problema, era el tipo de etiqueta que tenia en el HTML que mandaba a actualizar la información en la tabla que mencione gracias Santiago por que con tu respuesta pude darme cuenta de mi error,

Comment: que bueno que lo hayas solucionado, saludos